# Apache - separate log files for each auto subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I need to create separate log files for each subdomain. Regular expressions (%-3+) for some reason in parameter ErrorLog don't work.

```
ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/%-3+_error_log
```

Here is my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerName  %-3+.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/htdocs/%-3+

    <Directory "/var/www/example.com/htdocs">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

How to separate log files by subdomain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use variables in log location directives. The way to do it is to pipe the log to another program.

Here is a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217533/dynamic-apache-log-directory-based-on-hostname

Comment: Apparently not exist basic method is implemented without parsing logs.